# TikZ/PGF number in shape name

Tags: tikz-pgf, syntax

I'm currently creating my own shapes in TikZ. I'm trying to get a multiplexer to work, but I named the shape `mux4to1` and one of its anchors `D0`.

Basically, I'm getting a syntax error with the following code (MWE):

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,12pt,headsepline]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows.meta}

\makeatletter

% multiplexer shape    
\pgfdeclareshape{mux4to1}{
  % The 'minimum width' and 'minimum height' keys, not the content, determine
  % the size
  \savedanchor\northeast{%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\pgfshapeminwidth}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{\pgfshapeminheight}%
    \pgf@x=0.5\pgf@x
    \pgf@y=0.5\pgf@y
  }
  % This is redundant, but makes some things easier:
  \savedanchor\southwest{%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\pgfshapeminwidth}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{\pgfshapeminheight}%
    \pgf@x=-0.5\pgf@x
    \pgf@y=-0.5\pgf@y
  }
  % Inherit from rectangle
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]

  % Define same anchor a normal rectangle has
  \anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}
  \anchor{text}{
    \pgfpointorigin
    \advance\pgf@x by -.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \advance\pgf@y by -.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \advance\pgf@y by +.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox%
  }

  % Define anchors for signal ports
  \anchor{D0}{
    \northeast%
    \pgf@x=.75\pgf@x%
  }
  %...
  % Draw the box and the port labels
  \backgroundpath{
    %...

    \begingroup
    \tikzset{mux/port labels} % Use font from this style
    \tikz@textfont

    % ----------------------------------------------------------------
    \pgf@anchor@mux4to1@D0 % <--------------------- Syntax error here
    \pgftext[bottom,at={\pgfpoint{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}},y=\pgfshapeinnerysep]{0}
    % ----------------------------------------------------------------
    \endgroup

  }
}

% Key to add font macros to the current font
\tikzset{add font/.code={\expandafter\def\expandafter\tikz@textfont\expandafter{\tikz@textfont#1}}} 

% Define default style for this node
\tikzset{mux/port labels/.style={font=\sffamily\scriptsize}}
\tikzset{every mux4to1 node/.style={draw,minimum width=4cm,minimum 
height=1cm,very thick,inner sep=1mm,outer sep=0pt,cap=round,add 
font=\sffamily}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[mux4to1] (mux) {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I blatantly stole some stuff from [Texample:Example: D flip-flops and shift register](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/d-flip-flops-and-shift-register/) to help me get started.

My problem might be a general LaTeX or TeX error, as I noticed before that commands with numbers in them were problematic as well.

Ideally, a solution should not be to *just rename* the shape/anchor, if at all possible. Because `mux.Dzero, mux.Done` and so on are ugly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
    \pgf@anchor@mux4to1@D0 %
```

to

```
    \csname pgf@anchor@mux4to1@D0\endcsname %
```

The code:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,12pt,headsepline]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows.meta}

\makeatletter

% multiplexer shape    
\pgfdeclareshape{mux4to1}{
  % The 'minimum width' and 'minimum height' keys, not the content, determine
  % the size
  \savedanchor\northeast{%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\pgfshapeminwidth}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{\pgfshapeminheight}%
    \pgf@x=0.5\pgf@x
    \pgf@y=0.5\pgf@y
  }
  % This is redundant, but makes some things easier:
  \savedanchor\southwest{%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\pgfshapeminwidth}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{\pgfshapeminheight}%
    \pgf@x=-0.5\pgf@x
    \pgf@y=-0.5\pgf@y
  }
  % Inherit from rectangle
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]

  % Define same anchor a normal rectangle has
  \anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}
  \anchor{text}{
    \pgfpointorigin
    \advance\pgf@x by -.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \advance\pgf@y by -.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \advance\pgf@y by +.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox%
  }

  % Define anchors for signal ports
  \anchor{D0}{
    \northeast%
    \pgf@x=.75\pgf@x%
  }
  %...
  % Draw the box and the port labels
  \backgroundpath{
    %...

    \begingroup
    \tikzset{mux/port labels} % Use font from this style
    \tikz@textfont

    % ----------------------------------------------------------------
    \csname pgf@anchor@mux4to1@D0\endcsname %
    \pgftext[bottom,at={\pgfpoint{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}},y=\pgfshapeinnerysep]{0}
    % ----------------------------------------------------------------
    \endgroup

  }
}

% Key to add font macros to the current font
\tikzset{add font/.code={\expandafter\def\expandafter\tikz@textfont\expandafter{\tikz@textfont#1}}} 

% Define default style for this node
\tikzset{mux/port labels/.style={font=\sffamily\scriptsize}}
\tikzset{every mux4to1 node/.style={draw,minimum width=4cm,minimum 
height=1cm,very thick,inner sep=1mm,outer sep=0pt,cap=round,add 
font=\sffamily}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[mux4to1] (mux) {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The syntax error goes away. However, so does the desired effect of moving `\pgf@x`/`\pgf@y` to the location of the anchor. See http://imgur.com/vxnc9qr The bottom left corner is where I moved my path to before `\begingroup`.

Comment: Argh, never mind. I was subconsciously pretty-printing that to `\csname pgf@anchor@mux4to1@D0 \endcsname` -- notice the space -- which is obviously another command than without the space before `\endcsname`.